# Deleting file using spring cloud aws

Tags: amazon-s3, delete-file, spring-cloud-aws

I am exploring spring cloud aws for s3 operations instead of using amazonS3Client. I found documents for uploading and downloading files from s3 using resource loader. But I couldn't find any document related to moving or deleting the files from s3. Can we delete file from s3 using spring cloud aws?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304075/how-to-delete-file-from-s3-using-spring-cloud-aws