# How to delete file from S3 using Spring cloud AWS?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I could not find any API or documentation in Spring AWS Cloud to delete an object from S3 bucket. Can someone please let me know how to do it?

The [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) just talks about reading the content using `ResourceLoader`.

Only option right now I see is to explicitly inject `AmazonS3` and call `deleteObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring's Resource API does not support the full lifecycle of operations.  The two main interfaces are `Resource` and `WritableResource`.  There is no API for deletion.

As an alternative you could use [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for [S3](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/snapshot/s3-index.html) instead.  Spring Content Stores are all generic `ResourceLoader`s that return `Resource`s that DO support deletion.  That, by the way, works exactly as you are suggesting.

Take a look at the reference guide.  The base `Store` interface is the one that should be a straight drop-in for the one from Spring Cloud AWS.

Simply cast the return from `getResource` to `DeletableResource` and call it's `delete` to delete the object in S3.

Let me know if this is not clear and I can update with more details.